# Как вывести данные из массива объектов в таблицу JS?

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты

```js
let login = document.getElementById('login');
let password = document.getElementById('password');
let email = document.getElementById('email');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let blockOne = document.getElementById('blockOne');
let f1 = document.forms['f1'];
let tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
let users = [];

let getId = id => document.getElementById(id);

function User(userName, userPass, userEmail) {
  this.userName = userName;
  this.userPass = userPass;
  this.userEmail = userEmail;
}
btn.onclick = function() {
  let userName = login.value;
  let userPass = password.value;
  let userEmail = email.value;
  const newUser = new User(userName, userPass, userEmail);
  console.log(newUser);
  f1.reset();
  users.push(newUser);
  console.log(users);

  let tr = getId('tbody').append(document.createElement('tr'));
  for (const info of users) {
    console.log(info);
    for (const inf in newUser) {
      let td = document.createElement('td');
      td.textContent = newUser[inf];
      console.log(newUser[inf]);
      console.log(td);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.item {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#blockTwo {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="box" class="col-12 d-flex">
        <div id="blockOne" class="col-6 d-flex flex-column">
          <form name="f1">
            <div class="item">
              <h5>Login</h5>
              <input type="text" id="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Login">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h5>Password</h5>
              <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h5>Email</h5>
              <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <input type="button" id="btn" value="Add user" class="btn btn-outline-success col-4">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6" id="blockTwo">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Login</th>
                <th scope="col">Password</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Пользователь вводит свои данные в инпут поля и при нажатии на кнопку "add user" данные должны передаваться в массив объектов и этот же массив объектов должен передаваться в таблицу. Не могу понять что дальше делать с этим кодом. Там, где в thead ячейки edit и delete должны появляться кнопки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    let login = document.getElementById('login');
    let password = document.getElementById('password');
    let email = document.getElementById('email');
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    let blockOne = document.getElementById('blockOne');
    let f1 = document.forms['f1'];
    let tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
    let users = [];

    let getId = id => document.getElementById(id);

    btn.onclick = function() {
        let id = users.length + 1;
        let userName = login.value;
        let userPass = password.value;
        let userEmail = email.value;
        const temp = [id,userName,userPass,userEmail];
        users.push(temp);
        f1.reset();

        let tr = getId('tbody').append(document.createElement('tr'));
        let last = users[users.length - 1];
        for (const inf in last) {
            let td = document.createElement('td');
            td.textContent = last[inf];
            var doc = document.getElementById('tbody');
            doc.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
```

```html
<style>
    #box {
        margin-top: 70px;
    }

    .item {
        margin: 5px 0;
    }

    #blockTwo {
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
</style>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="box" class="col-12 d-flex">
            <div id="blockOne" class="col-6 d-flex flex-column">
                <form name="f1">
                    <div class="item">
                        <h5>Login</h5>
                        <input type="text" id="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Login">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h5>Password</h5>
                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h5>Email</h5>
                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Add user" class="btn btn-outline-success col-4">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6" id="blockTwo">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Login</th>
                        <th scope="col">Password</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tbody">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что-то меня смущает добавление клеток прямо в `tbody`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let login = document.getElementById('login');
let password = document.getElementById('password');
let email = document.getElementById('email');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let blockOne = document.getElementById('blockOne');
let f1 = document.forms['f1'];
let tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
let users = [];

let getId = id => document.getElementById(id);

function User(userName, userPass, userEmail) {
  this.userName = userName;
  this.userPass = userPass;
  this.userEmail = userEmail;
}
btn.onclick = function() {
  let userName = login.value;
  let userPass = password.value;
  let userEmail = email.value;
  const newUser = new User(userName, userPass, userEmail);
  //console.log(newUser);
  f1.reset();
  users.push(newUser);
  //console.log(users);

  let td;
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  getId('tbody').appendChild(tr);
  td = document.createElement('td');tr.appendChild(td);
  td.textContent = users.length;
  td = document.createElement('td');tr.appendChild(td);
  td.textContent = newUser.userName;
  td = document.createElement('td');tr.appendChild(td);
  td.textContent = newUser.userPass;
  td = document.createElement('td');tr.appendChild(td);
  td.textContent = newUser.userEmail;

  td = document.createElement('td');tr.appendChild(td);
  td = document.createElement('td');tr.appendChild(td);
  //    console.log(newUser[inf]);
  //    console.log(td);
}
```

```css
#box {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.item {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#blockTwo {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="box" class="col-12 d-flex">
      <div id="blockOne" class="col-6 d-flex flex-column">
        <form name="f1">
          <div class="item">
            <h5>Login</h5>
            <input type="text" id="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Login">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h5>Password</h5>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h5>Email</h5>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <input type="button" id="btn" value="Add user" class="btn btn-outline-success col-4">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6" id="blockTwo">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Login</th>
              <th scope="col">Password</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">Edit</th>
              <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tbody">

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```